# WPF Menu not staying at that the top

Tags: c#, wpf

OK here is my code :

```
<Window x:Class="Baileys.test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Baileys"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Bailey" Height="750" Width="832.579">


<Grid Margin="0,0,4.6,6.8" Height="716" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Play"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel></StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
    <local:CustomChartControl x:Name="Chart_Copy1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="102" Margin="9,332,-5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="789" BarsColor="SkyBlue" DataSource="C:\\data3.txt" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <local:CustomChartControl.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="0.15" AngleX="-0.139"/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform Y="1.16" X="-0.346"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </local:CustomChartControl.RenderTransform>
    </local:CustomChartControl>
    <local:CustomChartControl x:Name="Chart_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="86" Margin="9,221,-5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="789" BarsColor="SkyBlue" DataSource="C:\\data3.txt" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <local:CustomChartControl.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="0.15" AngleX="-0.139"/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform Y="1.16" X="-0.346"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </local:CustomChartControl.RenderTransform>
    </local:CustomChartControl>
    <local:CustomChartControl x:Name="Chart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="102" Margin="9,117,-5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="789" BarsColor="SkyBlue" DataSource="C:\\data3.txt" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <local:CustomChartControl.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="0.15" AngleX="-0.139"/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform Y="1.16" X="-0.346"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </local:CustomChartControl.RenderTransform>
    </local:CustomChartControl>
</Grid>
```

when I make my screen bigger, the menu is not at the top anymore...

Why?

why doesn't it not stay at the very top ?
ok I just updated, my code but it is still now staying at the top.
when I make my screen bigger, there is a big white gap from the very top to the menu

Comment: WFP??? You mean WPF?

Comment: WFP is Windows Filtering Platform, WPF is Windows Presentation Foundation :-)

Comment: It seems to that the menu is in the top because of the margin, but it isn't attached to there. Please view us the complete XAML.

Comment: Without the complete XAML code I could only guess, but maybe becuase `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"` in the `Grid`

Answer (score 0):

Try using DockPanel and dock it to the Top of your window.

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Play"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. please see my update

Comment: Try adding: VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" to your DockPanel. (See updated example above.)